# Stop automatic `conda activate` when opening a terminal in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda

VS Code has started running `conda activate` every time I open a terminal in VSCode, be it PowerShell, WSL, or CMD.

I never set this up intentionally so have no idea why it does this or how to disable it. I've looked at all my settings in VS Code and cannot find anything.

How do I stop VS Code from running `conda activate` when a new terminal is opened?

Comment: I've edited your question to be specifically about `conda activate` and not any command in general, since it really is only about that command, and the cause of this behaviour is also specific to that command.

Comment: Also, it's interesting that you say you get `conda activate` happening automatically in PowerShell. That's [documented to be unsupported](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environments-and-terminal-windows): "_Note: conda environments cannot be automatically activated in the integrated terminal if PowerShell is set as the integrated shell. See Integrated terminal - Terminal profiles for how to change the shell._" Just for curiosity's sake, can you double-check that?

Comment: Thanks. It's definitely doing it in powershell as I was using that all the time. Including opening multiple PS terminals. I nailed it down to the Python VSCode extension. Now I know how to disable, I'll try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the following in your settings.json file:

```json
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false
```

You're getting this behaviour because the default value of that setting is `true` if not specified.

For more info, see VS Code's docs on [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)- in particular, the [Working with Python interpreters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters)
 section, and the [Environments and Terminal windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environments-and-terminal-windows)
 section.

Quoting from that page:

> **Tip**: To prevent automatic activation of a selected environment, add `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false` to your `settings.json` file (it can be placed anywhere as a sibling to the existing settings).

Reading [the changelog, this setting was added in version `2018.9.0` of the Python extension for VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#201890-9-oct-2018). The PR that added it was [#1387](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1387).

Answer (score 0):

Open Powershell and run as Administrator, execute the following command

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base true
```

Then restart VS Code

Comment: Setting `auto_activate_base` to be `True` would activate the `base` environment, completely opposite of what the OP has asked. Also, PowerShell is irrelevant here as the issue is related to VS Code terminal.