# Why is the Visual Studio Code Terminal Defaulting to a Specific Source Folder? And how do I configure it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, pipenv, virtual-environment

When I spin up my Visual Studio Code environment and open the terminal, it automatically defaults to a specific source folder and spins up a specific pipenv virtual environment located inside the .local directory.

I've noticed that when I run the script files as well from a different pipenv (created in another .local virtual environment directory), it automatically reverts back to that same specific source folder.

Anyone have a way to fix this?

I have tried to go into my .zshrc file and have tried looking through a variety of settings inside of VS Code, but have not found anything that is showing me where this path is being defined.

Comment: What is in your workspace-level and folder-level settings.json? Did you previously select a Python interpreter for your workspace or folder?

Comment: Also, note that the ".local directory" is the _default_ location where pipenv stores virtual environment files. So each folder in .local corresponds to a virtual environment.

Comment: @GinoMempin yes I think that the python interpreter that was selected was causing this because it was automatically selecting the interpreter from an existing virtual environment.  Thank you for the help.  I was able to locate all the environments in the .local folder, but didn't realize that vscode was not defaulting to the global python settings.

Comment: "_it automatically defaults to a specific source folder_" defaults what? the working directory of the shell? and what exactly is that source folder?

Comment: see also [Stop automatic `conda activate` when opening a terminal in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74586089/11107541)

Comment: @starball when I spin up a new directory and a new pipenv in that folder the default python interpreter is a global value.  And in my case when I was running certain scripts in the shell it would switch to an old virtual environment.  I'm not entirely sure what was going on there, but I've noticed it again in another folder.  I spin up directory 1 with a pipenv1.  Then I change directories to directory 2 and set up pipenv2 and then notice that the virtual environment switches in directory 2 to pipenv1.  If I manually make the interpreter change it gets fixed.

Comment: weird. if you raise a bug report (`Help > Report Issue`), please ping me with a link to your issue ticket.

Comment: Okay.  Yeah I have noticed some buggy things with PipEnv a few times in recent days.  I'm finally getting the hang of it, but it does some odd things.  Like sometimes it starts a virtual environment in the parent directory even when I move to a specific folder.  Pipenv has been a little buggy, but since I'm so novice on this stuff I haven't ruled out user error.  All this is within VSCode btw.  Not sure if that helps.  I'm reluctant to open a bug report without being sure it's not me.  Any thoughts? @starball

Comment: no, sorry. I'm not that familiar with Python environment setup myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the python interpreter that was selected was causing this because it was automatically selecting either the global interpreter or another one from an existing virtual environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).